# Show element while AngularJS form is submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title suggests, I am trying to submit a form through Angular, and I want to have a little loading div that shows while the submit action is being carried out. Here is what I have at the moment.

View:

```
<div ng-app="SomeApp">
    <div ng-controller="SomeController" ng-init="submitting = false">
        <div id="LoadingOverlay" class="loadoverlay" ng-show="submitting">
            <img src="~/Content/img/loader.gif" class="loadspin" alt="Loading" />
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
            <!-- Some Form Controls Going On Here -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var setupApp = angular.module("SomeApp", []);
setupApp.controller("SomeController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.submitting = true;
        // Carry out the submit actions
        $scope.submitting = false;
    };
});
```

I tried changing the submitting bool with ng-click on the submit button, I tried jQuery, and I tried basically some angular wrapper for $().hide(), none of which are showing the loading gif while the submit actions are being carried out.

I should note that the submit actions (the stuff commented out) are all working as I would expect, all I'm doing in the submit angular action is an ajax call with $http and showing a message on success.

I found a couple pages showing some rather complicated looking solutions, so I wanted to come over here first, as a loading gif on a form submit is something I would think should be relatively simple to do.

Comment: Are you setting `$scope.submitting = false` within the $http response processing, or outside of that? If outside, then it looks possible that you're setting it to visible and then immediately making it invisible again. Your basic concept looks sound to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have your pseudo-code laid out makes it look like you might be doing something like:

**Wrong version**

```
var setupApp = angular.module("SomeApp", []);
setupApp.controller("SomeController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.submitting = true;

        // Carry out the submit actions
        $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: '/someUrl'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
           // called asynchronously if an error occurs
           // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

        $scope.submitting = false;
    };
});
```

If this is the case, then you make your loading image visible, initiate your `$http` request, and then immediately turn off your submitting flag again.  You want to put the `$scope.submitting = false;` within your callback functions and not outside of the async process, like this:

**Right version:**

```
        $scope.submitting = true;

        // Carry out the submit actions
        $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: '/someUrl'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            $scope.submitting = false;
            // do stuff

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
           // called asynchronously if an error occurs
           // or server returns response with an error status.
           $scope.submitting = false;
           // do stuff

        });
```

Comment: You would put $scope.submitting = false; inside what you call the successCallback (the promise resolution) AND inside the errorCallback method. You could use anon functions. As it stands scope.submitting = false will be executed immediately which is not what the asker wants.

Comment: much better nice code :) although a POST is more likely for a submit

Comment: Yes, I was showing what I think he's doing in the code, then said what he should change it to, but I didn't show that, and it was a bit confusing. Added an explicit corrected version for clarity.

Comment: @danday74 Fair enough - updated. Although I think we'd be better off if the OP would edit the question to include the actual submit actions, since I *think* that's where the issue is, but it's still just speculation at this point. :)

Comment: On my phone in a meeting at the moment, however I think you both are correct, I'll update my post with what I was doing and pick and answer when I get back to a computer. I knew it was going to be something like this, I spent an embarrassing amount of time pulling my hair out over this haha. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

in your $scope.submit you do ...

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.submitting = true;
    var postData = {name:"fred"};
    $http.post("/your/url", postData).then(function(response) {
        // Carry out the success actions
        $scope.submitting = false;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Carry out the failure actions
        $scope.submitting = false;
    });  
};
```

This works because the $http service returns a promise. Promise's have a THEN method which are executed when the $http request is complete. The catch block is executed on a non 200 HTTP response or on failure (eg timeout).

Comment: I'd suggest that they use `.finally( function(){ $scope.submitting = false; })` so as to avoid code duplication since `finally` gets executed for both *success* and *failure* scenarios.